# MVC 3 RAZOR create text box dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to create textbox dynamically based on item count in collection using mvc 3 razor. Also once created how do we read the values entered in those.

Comment: try to solve by creating editor template..

Answer (score 2):

What i've done is create a helper in a .cshtml file in my App_Code folder that creates a textbox:

```
@helper CreateTextBox(string id)
{
    <input type="text" id="@id"/>
}
```

Then in my view I can create the textboxes dynamically:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Applications)
{
    @MyHelpers.CreateTextBox("textBoxAppId" + item.ApplicationId)       //you can also use your own index here
}
```

When trying to read my input after a postback, I just loop thru parameters in the Request.Form that start with 'textBoxAppId'

Comment: Or you can even just skip the helper & put the input tag in the loop